# Do questions about ethical living belong here – and if not, where?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Logically it seems to me that a question about ethical living, such as fair sharing of resources or welfare of farm animals need not be on topic for Sustainable Living, yet they seem very similar in character to the questions here. Moreover, the decision to live sustainably will often be taken on ethical grounds. Are such questions on topic here? (In the main site rather than meta, of course!) If not, is there an appropriate community for such questions? I have found nothing in *All Sites* or *Area 51*.

Comment: I think if the question is about the _ethics_ of sustainable living, in a broad sense, then it probably fits better as an ethics-tagged question in [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics).

Comment: With specific regard to farm animals, questions about welfare of farm animals, especially cows and chickens, may be on-topic on [Vegetarianism.SE](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @LShaver: I feel that a question would only belong on _Philosophy_ if it were not about practicalities: _Which of these labels/logos is to be preferred on ethical criteria?_ is clearly not a philosophical question.

Comment: @Nic: Animal welfare questions certainly seem a moderately good fit on _Vegetarianism_, but ethical living is broader, and it seems a shame that there is no way of collecting questions about it. The obvious response is that I ought to launch something in _Area 51_, but I fear that I do not have the time for that, which might well turn out a damp squib anyway.